# Solving quadratic equation in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to build my first ASP.NET MVC Application which solves quadratic equation, but I am having problem displaying my result to the View. 
Here is my **Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Resolve.Models
{
public class Solve
{
    public double a { get; set; }
    public double b { get; set; }
    public double c { get; set; }
    public double x1 { get; set; }
    public double x2 { get; set; }

   public void Calculate (out double x1, out double x2)
    {
        double inside = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;

        if (inside < 0)
        {
            x1 = double.NaN;
            x2 = double.NaN;
        }
        else
        {
            double eqn = Math.Sqrt(inside);
            x1 = (-b + eqn) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - eqn) / (2 * a);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Resolve.Controllers
{
public class EquationController : Controller
{
 // GET: Equation
    public ActionResult Promise()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Promise(Solve equation)
    {

        return View(equation);
    }
 }
 }
```

**View**

```
  @model Resolve.Models.Solve

 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Promise";
 }

<h2>Promise</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Solve</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.a, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
 "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.a, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
 @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.a, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.b, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
"control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.b, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
@class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.b, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.c, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
"control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.c, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
 @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.c, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Model.x1 : </p> <p>Model.x2</p>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Solve" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}



@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I am really having problem displaying the result to the View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

Firstly, you never call `Calculate` function in the first place. Thus, your `Solve` model never got their `x1` and `x2` calculated.

Secondly, since you put two parameters `x1` and `x2` as input for `Calculate` function, they "mask" the `Solve` model fields `x1` and `x2` - which you use to display the result in the View. You should also take them out.

And thirdly, as you you have found, the syntax for `Model.x1` and `Model.x2` should be using `@` as prefix (i.e. `@Model.x1`) to indicate that it is a razor syntax.

This is what you should do:

**Model Method**

```
public void Calculate () //removes the out double for x1 and x2
{
    double inside = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;

    if (inside < 0)
    {
        x1 = double.NaN;
        x2 = double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        double eqn = Math.Sqrt(inside);
        x1 = (-b + eqn) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - eqn) / (2 * a);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Resolve.Controllers
{

    public class EquationController : Controller
    {
     // GET: Equation
        public ActionResult Promise()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] //don't use this
        [HttpPost] //use this instead
        public ActionResult Promise(Solve equation)
        {
            equation.Calculate(); //calls this
            return View(equation);
        }
     }         

 }
```

**View**

```
<p>@Model.x1 : </p> <p>@Model.x2</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian, after following your instructions I still have some problems getting result in the view. This is how I am displaying the result <p>Model.x1 : </p> <p>Model.x2</p>.

Comment: @Izuagbala perhaps you could post your entire `View`?

Comment: But how can I do that . This is my first time on stackoverflow

Comment: Press edit on your post, then paste your entire View in the right portion of your edit box

Comment: Just pasted the the entire view

Comment: Ok, what is the error this time? Did you *not* getting `x1` and `x2` values at all, or that they show `0`?

Comment: There is no values at all for x1 and x2

Comment: I get it, try to put [HttpPost] attribute on top of the second `ActionResult`, I will change my answer in a second to show that...

Comment: Thank Man you are great. I just got the answer. I was displaying  Model.x1 in the browser instead of using razor syntax. Thanks again. Can I chat you up ?

Comment: I see, I missed that... I thought you have `empty` result instead of having `Model.x1` printed out. Oh, you have another question?

Comment: I edited my answer to suit the actual problem, please do not forget to accept it (tick V symbol in the left side of the answer) to indicate that the question already have an accepted answer. Also, this way, both of us will get a little reputation up which will be useful for unlocking features in the stack overflow (including chat) :D See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges for more details

Comment: Just clicked the V symbol. Do you mean I cant chat you up. I just got a programmer job and I will need a strong hand when I get some problems that is the reason I want to reach you

Comment: I think there is a privilege requirement need to chat. See the page of the link I posted. Only if your reputation is > 20. But if your concern is you want to get strong hand, do not worry. ;) just post your questions/look for the answers in SO. There are handful of "strong hands" out there which are ready to help you, especially during working hours in USA.